# Parallel/concurrent calls in vertx

Tags: java, asynchronous, vert.x

I am reading data from database in backend(vertx code)and each row has a url on which I will do a "GET" http request for the status field in response which i am storing back into database and sending to UI.

CreateRequests method makes http requests.I want to do this concurrently.

```
        List<Future> toComplete=new ArrayList<>();
        Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();int i;
        for(i=0;i<requestsListInDept.size();i++)
        {
            String reqtype = requestsListInDept.getString(i);
            JsonObject requestProperties = dataReader.getRequestProperties(dept,reqtype);
           toComplete.add(Future.future());
           int currrent=i;
            vertx.executeBlocking(future->{
                System.out.println("calling for ");
                String individualResponse  = accReq.createRequests(requestContext,reqtype,empid,requestProperties);
               toComplete.get(currrent).complete(individualResponse);
                future.complete(individualResponse);
            },false,res->{
                JsonArray obj=new JsonArray( (res.result()).toString() );
                for(int index=0;index<obj.size();index++)
                {
                    JsonObject requestResponse=obj.getJsonObject(index);
                    response.add(requestResponse);

                }
                toComplete.get(currrent).complete(res.result());
            });
        }
      CompositeFuture.all(toComplete).setHandler(e -> {
                String collect = e.result()
                        .list()
                        .stream()
                        .map(Object::toString)
                        .collect(Collectors.joining(" ------- "));
                System.out.println(collect);
            });

return ;
```

How can I efficiently make concurrent get calls and combine responses(which i will be sending to UI) and store them back to DB

I am looping all the urls and making get requests in loop.If there is large data I am getting Timeout(That's obvious)

Answer (score 0):

Vert.x use the reactor pattern, so you could achieve a similar result using the pattern rather than multithreading and executeBlocking. Using multithreading and blocking calls in Vert.x is recommended only when there is no way to support the pattern (meaning, there is no async way of doing it).

Maybe this example can help you

```
  public void doCall() {
    List<Future> toComplete = new ArrayList<>();
    WebClientOptions options = new WebClientOptions().setSsl(true);
    WebClient webClient = WebClient.create(Vertx.vertx(), options);
    IntStream.range(0, 15).forEach(counter -> {
      toComplete.add(Future.future());
      int current = counter;
      webClient.get(443, "google.com", "/")
               .send(httpResponseAsyncResult -> {
                 String googleResult = httpResponseAsyncResult.result().bodyAsString();
                 toComplete.get(current).complete(googleResult);
               });
      System.out.println("Calling google: times " + ++counter);
    });
    CompositeFuture.all(toComplete).setHandler(e -> {
      String collect = e.result()
                        .list()
                        .stream()
                        .map(Object::toString)
                        .collect(Collectors.joining(" ------- "));
      System.out.println(collect);
    });
  }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This works but can we put something like compositfuture.all for waiting for all the futur responses instead of putting thread.sleep()

Comment: thread sleep() can be completely removed. I put it just to show the output in which you are calling and receiving otherwise you would not have the feeling of the parallelism because it is faster in iterating 15 times than in having the first response from the http call. So you would have seen calling calling calling ... receiving receiving receiving. You can also use compositeFuture.all instead of the custom collector I wrote

Comment: @ammy I rewrote it to use the CompositeFuture.all() without the custom collector.

Comment: please look at my code(edited),I have made the changes you told.But Compositefuture.all is not waiting for all the future objects.Why is this happening?

Comment: Because your future is created only when the call is completed and when you exit the for loop some threads might be running. Add an empty future outside the executeBlocking (future.future()) and retrieve it inside the executeBlocking as I did in my example (added as first line in the loop and positionally retrieved inside the handler of the send)

Comment: can you check once.Still couldn't get that

Comment: You are not completing the future of the list. Before future.complete(individualResponse) do toComplete.get(i).complete(individualResponse)

Comment: sorry for not being clear. Compositefuture.all is not waiting for all the future objects.

Comment: Just read the documentation of executeBlocking, sorry my fault - the toComplete.get(current).complete () has to be only in result handler (is already there) and has to be removed before future.complete() - I did not read doc I assumed it was success and error handler, while is code and response handler. If not working try to debug